# Cron service in multiple k8s pod

Tags: kubernetes, cron

I have an application running on multiple k8s pods. Forgive me for my lack of knowledge about k8s pod, from my understanding k8s will route incoming traffic to a different pod just like a proxy.

What happened if my application is running a cron job that fetches data. Is the cron job gonna be called multiple times based on how much pod is running, my concern is that will be a data duplication because these pod will fetch the same data.

My question is how to avoid data duplication when a cron job fetches data? can these pod configured to become something like a worker? let's say the cron job is fetching 500 data. Given 5 pods, each pod will fetch 100 data.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, it should be not like that way POD will be mostly running the workload like API or socket servers

For cronjobs there are other options n Kubernetes is especially for the cronjob.

There are **cronjobs** & **jobs** two things in Kubernetes.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/

cron jobs get executed as per the corn timing while jobs get executed when you create it using YAML.

Cronjob indirectly creates the **job** run time. you can check out using the `kubectl get jobs` & `kubectl get cronjobs`

> can these pod configured to become something like a worker? let's say
> the cron job is fetching 500 data. Given 5 pods, each pod will fetch
> 100 data.

now this depends on your scenrio you can create the single cronjob which fetch all those 500 data and single pod will be running at a time or corn execution.

> My question is how to avoid data duplication when a cron job fetches
> data?

Run that type of workload as Cronjob pod.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/